# std::mutiset vs std::vector.Getting TLE in one code but AC in another

Tags: c++, sorting, time-complexity, binary-search, multiset

Problem Link: https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1091/

I am assuming there is some kind of issue relating to time complexity but I am unable to identify what I am doing wrong here.

**Getting Time Limit Exceeded verdict in this code:**

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define int long long int
main()
{
    int n,m;
    scanf("%lld %lld",&n,&m);
    vector<int>tickets;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int x;
        scanf("%lld",&x);
        tickets.push_back(x);
    }
    sort(tickets.begin(),tickets.end());
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        int x;
        scanf("%lld",&x);
        auto index=lower_bound(tickets.begin(),tickets.end(),x);
        if(index==tickets.begin() and (*index>x or index==tickets.end()))
            printf("-1\n");
        else
        {
            if(*index!=x)
                index--;
            printf("%lld\n",*index);
            tickets.erase(index);
        }
    }
}
```

**Getting Accepted verdict in this code:**

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define int long long int
main()
{
    int n,m;
    scanf("%lld %lld",&n,&m);
    multiset<int>tickets;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int x;
        scanf("%lld",&x);
        tickets.insert(x);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        int x;
        scanf("%lld",&x);
        auto index=tickets.lower_bound(x);
        if(index==tickets.begin() and (*index>x or index==tickets.end()))
            printf("-1\n");
        else
        {
            if(*index!=x)
                index--;
            printf("%lld\n",*index);
            tickets.erase(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Not understanding why is this happening.

Comment: the fact that you are sorting the vector before evaluation can be a reason for increased running time of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `tickets.erase(index)` statement that you are using.

In vectors (no matter sorted or not), `erase()` is `O(n)` while for multiset `erase()` is `O(logn)` typically.

So, when you are using a vector and then using `erase()` in a for loop of size `m`, you get extra `O(n)` for each iteration of `i` and thus a total complexity of
`O(nlogn (sorting) + m * (logn (lower_bound) + n (erase))) = O(m*n)` which is way too much.

But for multiset, using `erase()` gets you extra `O(logn)` for each iteration resulting in total time complexity of
`O(nlogn (insert into multiset) + m * (logn (lower_bound) + logn (erase)) = O((m + n)logn)`.

I hope it clears your doubt. Read below links for better understanding.
[vector erase time complexity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)
[multiset erase time complexity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/erase)